# What is the best way to take database backup separately per club/user

Tags: mysql, database

I have a situation to solve.

Ok, so we have a system where lots of clubs are joining and they have their own data sets.
Own players, tournaments, results, etc going on.
I am doing it with one database having separate club ids. This works really fine, but problems occur when some make terrible mistakes we need to do some backup. So for backup, we have to take the whole database backup just to fix one club data. So in this process, all other clubs are in a stupid state.
In this case, how do you take backup for your database?

Thank you.

Comment: Backups are not intended for the correction of user input mistakes. They are used when there's a problem with the database. Perhaps you can make some system to roll back changes that users have made?

Comment: Ok, the problem is, the system admin can make mistakes and some other reason, we need to restore old state if some bad action happens

Comment: Ummm perhaps you should make sure that the data is correct before allowing the user to input it using assertions??